# Train delays - Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text

Tags: r, while-loop

I designed the following scripts months ago and it worked without any issue. The last few days I tried to rerun the same script but always got the same error. I've changed my script and updating the packages, but i'm unable to make it work again. The script should give me all the delays in the Belgian railroad stations.

I have add my two separate scripts (one is filled with the functions) and the error/traceback.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

load.stations <- function(){
  a <- GET("https://api.irail.be/stations/?format=json") #get command for all stations from irail api
  parsed <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(a, "text"), flatten=TRUE) #parse json into r
  stations <- parsed$station %>% 
    filter(grepl("^BE.NMBS.0088",id)) #keep only stations in Belgium. Regular expression ^ is begins with  
  return(stations)
}

get.time <- function(){
  time <- paste(format(Sys.time(),"%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")) #formats system time in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss in a string
  strpt <- strptime(time,"%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S") #takes time-string and converts to interpretable date and time
  return(strpt)
}

get.temp_df <- function(stations, i){
  goget <- paste0("https://api.irail.be/liveboard/?format=json&id=",stations$id[i]) #http for get command, get liveboard (similar to screens in station i)
  c <- GET(goget) #get the data
  parsed_c <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(c, "text"), flatten=TRUE) #parse from json
  temp_df <- parsed_c$departures$departure #get the dataframe with departures from the parsed json
  return(temp_df)
}

add.to.all <- function(all_df, temp_df){
  all_df <- rbind(all_df,temp_df)%>% #add temporary dataframe to master dataframe
    group_by(stationneke,time,vehicle)%>% # group departure times by station - remove doubles
    top_n(1,importtime)%>% #only keep the most recent observation  - remove doubles 2
    ungroup() #lift grouping
  return(all_df)
}

save.day <- function(all_df){
  strpt <- get.time()
  saveRDS(all_df,file = paste(strpt$mday, strpt$mon+1, strpt$year+1900,"Punct.rda",sep = "-"))
  Sys.sleep(time = 3600-(strpt$min*60+strpt$sec)) #sleep one hour minus number of secs in the sleep time
  return(data.frame())
}
```

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

## all departures - scraper

loop.scraper <- function(hour_of_pause =3){
  source("NMBS-punctuality-functions.R")
  all_df <- data.frame() #leeg dataframe
  stations <- load.stations()
  while (TRUE) { #infinite loop
    strpt <- get.time()
    while(strpt$hour != hour_of_pause){ #enters loop when hour is not "hour_of_pause"
      # startloop <- (strpt$min*60 + strpt$sec)
      for (i in 1:nrow(stations)) { #second loop through the stations
        temp_df <- get.temp_df(stations, i)
        if(is.null(temp_df)) next #skip if dataframe is empty (some stations have been closed in recent years)
        temp_df$stationneke <- stations$name[i] #add departure station name i to the dataframe
        temp_df$importtime <- Sys.time() # add variable with the time of import of the observation
        all_df <- add.to.all(all_df, temp_df)
        strpt <- get.time()
      } #end of loop through stations
      # stoploop <- (strpt$min*60 + strpt$sec)
    } #end of hour-check loop, code below only executed when no trains active (at night)
    all_df <- save.day(all_df) #saves file and returns empty dataframe
  }
}
```

```
 Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>:  Unc
                     (right here) ------^ 
5.
parse_string(txt, bigint_as_char) 
4.
parseJSON(txt, bigint_as_char) 
3.
parse_and_simplify(txt = txt, simplifyVector = simplifyVector, 
    simplifyDataFrame = simplifyDataFrame, simplifyMatrix = simplifyMatrix, 
    flatten = flatten, ...) 
2.
jsonlite::fromJSON(content(c, "text"), flatten = TRUE) 
1.
loop.scraper(12)
```

Comment: That error looks like there is something wrong with the data coming from the website you are scraping, not your script. Perhaps the format has changed.

Comment: That could explain why the code worked previously... I'll investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe print out the value of `i` on your loop so you can see which value it's getting the error on.